# Does Mystic shield + Starmantle destroy magic weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Starmantle destroys nonmagical weapons.

Mystic Shield says:

> A mystic shield also negates the enhancement bonuses and special properties of magic weapons used against the target.

Does this mean that when under the effects of both spells, a magical weapon attacking you will be destroyed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Mystic shield* doesn’t say it makes the weapon nonmagical, just that it negates the enhancement bonuses and special properties for attacks against the target. It’s still magical, so *starmantle* can do nothing to it.

Actually, for that matter, *antimagic field* still doesn’t let *starmantle* destroy magic weapons; they are still magic weapons, even if their magic isn’t functioning.

Also, just as an aside: *starmantle* is a really problematic spell. In fact, most of *Book of Exalted Deeds* is rather problematic. I advise caution when dealing with its material. It’s got a handful of excellent options (Intuitive Attack, Nymph’s Kiss, and *soulfire* are some of my favorite options in the system), but much of it is just bad, or bad for the game (like *starmantle*, or any of Vows).